Is this legal to fly with passengers at dusk or dawn without night currency?
In USA, as per 14 CFR § 61.57, night currency requires three full stop takeoff/landings one hour after sunset and one hour before sunrise.
If a pilot is NOT night current but is day current, does the rules implicitly mean within the hour after sunset and within the hour before sunrise, is also considered part of the day currency?
As an example, the PIC can fly with passengers during this time frame even though it may be dark?

Yes.
Per 14 CFR 61.57:

Except as provided in paragraph (e) of this section, no person may act as pilot in command of an aircraft carrying passengers during the period beginning 1 hour after sunset and ending 1 hour before sunrise, unless within the preceding 90 days that person has made at least three takeoffs and three landings to a full stop during the period beginning 1 hour after sunset and ending 1 hour before sunrise, and—

It's worded as a negative, but if you are day current you can act as PIC with passengers during the times specified.
It's worth noting that there are different regulations that cover logging night time, or when lights are required.  Here is a link to an article explaining these differences:  When can you log night flight and night landings?

The 1 hour before/ 1 hour after rule is for logging currency only. The "night" time for carrying passengers is the end of evening civil twilight to beginning of morning civil twilight which is defined as the sun being 6 degrees below the horizon. This time completely depends on your latitude and time of year. In the lower 49 states (minus Alaska) the average time for civil twilight is approximately 20-30 minutes after sunset/20-30 minutes before sunrise. So if you are flying in the evening, you have about 20-30 minutes after sunset where it is legal without night currency, but after that, it is illegal.

34-37 minutes at 45deg latitude (portland), 30-33 minutes at 40deg (nyc), 28-29 minutes at 35deg latitude (los angeles), 27 minutes at 30deg (orlando). 20-30 is a good rule of thumb, just giving winter (short) and summer (long) times.

No, 61.57 says you can act as PIC with pax 1 hour past sunset.  Logging is different, you just got your regs mixed up... (see the link in my answer)
